# General regarding service class and multithreading

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite

I am running a code, where the user selects a date and time. The user can select any date and time in the future. These dates and time are stored in sqlite database. After the user selects those dates and time, the activity calls a service class, where I am running a new thread in the following way

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    final SqliteController db = new SqliteController(getApplicationContext());

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            List<Greetings> greetings = db.getAllGreetings();
            if (db.getGreetingsCount() >= 0) {
                do {
                    for (Greetings g : greetings) {
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                      .........
                      .........//other codes
```

This thread access the data from the database and matches the time and date with the system time and date. One the date and time matches, I am using alarm manager with broadcast receiver like this

```
if (dnt.equals(cdt)) {
             Intent aint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

              aint.putExtra("msg", msg);
              aint.putExtra("phone", phone);
              aint.putExtra("id", id);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, aint, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
          db.deleteGreetings(g);
                        }
```

### I wanted to know, Is this the correct way to do it? When I run the program in emulator, sometimes it runs fine, but other times it shows "Application doing too much work in the main thread". So, am I doing something wrong? or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Since nearly all of your posted code is running in a background thread, this would not cause your application to be doing too much work in the main thread.  Your problem is likely coming from another source.

You could try profiling your app using traceview as described in the Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html). Try to find which methods are consuming the most time to narrow down your search.

As an aside, you should use an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) instead of a Service if your service is just creating a single thread running this task in the background. You then implement the onHandleIntent method instead of the onStartCommand method. The IntentService will handle all operations it receives in a single background Looper.

Comment: Thanks, I will try out the traceview and intentservice method.